# absoluteness and logical equivalence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Kunen's (outstanding) Set Theory.  On page 96 (of the 2nd edition) he notes various formulas which are absolute for all transitive models.  I have two questions.  First, when Kunen describes a formula as being "logically equivalent" to a delta_0 formula, does he mean provably equivalent in, say, ZF minus Foundation and Replacement, or literally logically equivalent?  Second, just to confirm that I understand the notion, any logical truth (even if not a sentence) is absolute for any models whatever, yes?